# Time Limit Exceeded when running a program for "Kth Smallest element in an array"

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I attempted this question on **GeeksForGeeks** [Kth Smallest Element in an Array](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/kth-smallest-element5635/1) (GFG) and it worked fine and it passed ***106/156*** testcases, just when I thought that I had solved the question, i got a popup on screen stating that *Time Limit Reached* I want to know how my solution can be optimized in order for it to be accepted. By the way, I used max heap in order to approach this problem. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

**Code**

```
class Solution{
public static int kthSmallest(int[] a, int l, int r, int k) 
{ 
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq= new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        pq.add(a[i]);
    }
    for(int i=k;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        if(pq.peek() > a[i])
        {
            pq.poll();
            pq.add(a[i]);
        }
    }
    return pq.peek();
}
```

}

Comment: do you have any idea why method has `int l` and `int r` params? [Quickselect Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quickselect-algorithm/)

Comment: In the question it is stated that ```l points to start and r points to end index of the array```, I suppose they want the answer strictly in form of two-pointer approach

Comment: please check implementations of `Quickselect Algorithm`, the purpose of `int l` and `int r` is to perform recursive calls of `kthSmallest` method

Comment: @Andrey B. Panfilov  I am aware about that, but is there any way other than that, to solve this problem??

Comment: That is definitely `Quick Select` problem - provide algorithm with `O(n)` time complexity, your heap solution has `O(nlogk)` time complexity, that is the reason why you get TLE.